# Trying to run an executable with paremeters from Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, executable

I'm trying to run the following executable with parameters from Powershell:

`wgrib2.exe test_t.grib -if  "^(1|2):" -grid_def -else -s -lola 0:360:1 -90:181:1 1x1_t.grib grib -endif`

So far I've tried several different methods but none have worked. Initially using cmd.exe:

```
$wg=  test_t.grib -if "^(1|2):" -grid_def -else -s -lola 0:360:1 -90:181:1 1x1_t.grib grib -endif

$jobregrid = Start-Job { cmd.exe  /c F:; chdir F:\nwp\global\grib; wgrib2.exe $using:wg"  }

Wait-Job $jobregrid
Receive-Job $jobregrid
$jobregrid = $null
```

Also tried Invoke-Expression and Start-Process.

The command works when run directly from a DOS prompt or from a batch file. The problem seems to be that I don't understand PowerShell syntax sufficiently to deal with "^(1|2):" section. I have tried using the escape character ` but I still can't get it to work.

Help please?

Brian

Comment: What happens if you try `$wg=  'test_t.grib -if "^(1|2):" -grid_def -else -s -lola 0:360:1 -90:181:1 1x1_t.grib grib -endif'`

Comment: AdminOfThings: That gives me the following error message 
`could not open file: test_t.grib -if ^(1|2): -grid_def -else -s -lola 0:360:1 -90:181:1 1x1_t.grib grib -endif ***`